# How to extract the string pattern in C++ efficiently?

Tags: c++

I have a pattern that in the following format:

```
AUTHOR, "TITLE" (PAGES pp.) [CODE STATUS]
```

For example, I have a string

```
P.G. Wodehouse, "Heavy Weather" (336 pp.) [PH.409 AVAILABLE FOR LENDING]
```

I want to extract

```
AUTHOR = P.G. Wodehouse
TITLE = Heavy Weather
PAGES = 336
CODE = PH.409
STATUS = AVAILABLE FOR LENDING
```

I only know how to do that in Python, however, are there any efficient way to do the same thing in C++?

Comment: Read the line character by character, if it equals the start/end of one of the elements, save what comes before/after it.

Comment: Use [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Comment: @Boop If he's using Python, he knows regular expressions, which make the entire code much, much simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly the same way as in Python.  C++11 has regular expressions (and for earlier C++, there's Boost regex.)  As for the read loop:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

is almost exactly the same as:

```
for line in file:
    #    ...
```

The only differences are:

- The C++ version will not put the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer.  (In general, the C++ version may be less flexible with regards to end of line handling.)
- In case of a read error, the C++ version will break the loop; the Python version will raise an exception.

Neither should be an issue in your case.

### EDIT:

It just occurs to me that while regular expressions in C++ and in Python are very similar, the syntax for using them isn't quite the same.  So:

In C++, you'd normally declare an instance of the regular expression before using it; something like Python's `re.match( r'...', line )` is theoretically possible, but not very idiomatic (and it would still involve explicitly constructuing a regular expression object in the expression).  Also, the match function simply returns a boolean; if you want the captures, you need to define a separate object for them.  Typical use would probably be something like:

```
static std::regex const matcher( "the regular expression" );
std::smatch forCaptures;
if ( std::regex_match( line, forCaptures, matcher ) ) {
    std::string firstCapture = forCaptures[1];
    //  ...
}
```

This corresponds to the Python:

```
m = re.match( 'the regular expression', line )
if m:
    firstCapture = m.group(1)
    #   ...
```

EDIT:

Another answer has suggested overloading `operator>>`; I heartily concur.  Just out of curiousity, I gave it a go; something like the following works well:

```
struct Book
{
    std::string author;
    std::string title;
    int         pages;
    std::string code;
    std::string status;
};

std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, Book& dest )
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline( source, line );
    if ( source )
    {
        static std::regex const matcher(
            R"^(([^,]*),\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\((\d+) pp.\)\s*\[(\S+)\s*([^\]]*)\])^"
            ); 
        std::smatch capture;
        if ( ! std::regex_match( line, capture, matcher ) ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        } else {
            dest.author = capture[1];
            dest.title  = capture[2];
            dest.pages  = std::stoi( capture[3] );
            dest.code   = capture[4];
            dest.status = capture[5];
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

Once you've done this, you can write things like:

```
std::vector<Book> v( (std::istream_iterator<Book>( inputFile )),
                     (std::istream_iterator<Book>()) );
```

And load an entire file in the initialization of a vector.

Note the error handling in the `operator>>`.  If a line is misformed, we set `failbit`; this is the standard convention in C++.

EDIT:

Since there's been so much discussion: the above is fine for small, one time programs, things like school projects, or one time programs which will read the current file, output it in a new format, and then be thrown away.  In production code, I would insist on support for comments and empty lines; continuing in case of error, in order to report multiple errors (with line numbers), and probably continuation lines (since titles can get long enough to become unwieldly).  It's not practical to do this with `operator>>`, if for no other reason than the need to output line numbers, so I'd use a parser along the following line:

```
int
getContinuationLines( std::istream& source, std::string& line )
{
    int results = 0;
    while ( source.peek() == '&' ) {
        std::string more;
        std::getline( source, more );   //  Cannot fail, because of peek
        more[0] = ' ';
        line += more;
        ++ results;
    }
    return results;
}

void
trimComment( std::string& line )
{
    char quoted = '\0';
    std::string::iterator position = line.begin();
    while ( position != line.end() && (quoted != '\0' || *position == '#') ) {
        if ( *position == '\' && std::next( position ) != line.end() ) {
            ++ position;
        } else if ( *position == quoted ) {
            quoted = '\0';
        } else if ( *position == '\"' || *position == '\'' ) {
            quoted = *position;
        }
        ++ position;
    }
    line.erase( position, line.end() );
}

bool
isEmpty( std::string const& line )
{
    return std::all_of(
        line.begin(),
        line.end(),
        []( unsigned char ch ) { return isspace( ch ); } );
}

std::vector<Book>
parseFile( std::istream& source )
{
    std::vector<Book> results;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    std::string line;
    bool errorSeen = false;
    while ( std::getline( source, line ) ) {
        ++ lineNumber;
        int extraLines = getContinuationLines( source, line );
        trimComment( line );
        if ( ! isEmpty( line ) ) {
            static std::regex const matcher(
                R"^(([^,]*),\s*"([^"]*)"\s*\((\d+) pp.\)\s*\[(\S+)\s*([^\]]*)\])^"
                ); 
            std::smatch capture;
            if ( ! std::regex_match( line, capture, matcher ) ) {
                std::cerr << "Format error, line " << lineNumber << std::endl;
                errorSeen = true;
            } else {
                results.emplace_back(
                    capture[1],
                    capture[2],
                    std::stoi( capture[3] ),
                    capture[4],
                    capture[5] );
            }
        }
        lineNumber += extraLines;
    }
    if ( errorSeen ) {
        results.clear();    //  Or more likely, throw some sort of exception.
    }
    return results;
}
```

The real issue here is how you report the error to the caller; I suspect that in most cases, and exception would be appropriate, but depending on the use case, other alternatives may be valid as well.  In this example, I just return an empty vector.  (The interaction between comments and continuation lines probably needs to be better defined as well, with modifications according to how it has been defined.)

Comment: what's that `std::read`? Did you perhaps mean [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: @BoBTFish Definitely.  I've fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: @BoBTFish And good point with regards to the reference.  While the regular expressions themselves are very similar, there are significant differences in the way they are used.  i've updated my answer to provide a simple example of how to do it in C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze Nice, not bad at all for someone who thinks: "`istream_iterator` is rarely useful in practice because it of the problems involving error handling." Note to the user: this extraction operator will have undesirable effects if there is more than one `book` on the line or if there is any other data on the line.

Comment: @JonathanMee Rarely doesn't mean never.  In my experience, it's rare for a file to consist of just one data type, and to want to read it until end of file parsing just that data type.  I also wouldn't use the vector/istream_iterator solution in production code; in production code, when I find an error in a record, I want to continue anyway, to report _all_ of the errors I've seen.  I also want to provide for comments in the input file.  (There are techniques of doing both using filtering streambufs, but in this case, they'd probably be more complicated than a simple loop using my operator.)

Comment: @JonathanMee With regards to the "undesirable effects" if there is more than one `book` on the line, or if there is other data: the program wouldn't be correct without them.  Input has a specified format, and a correct program will detect when it doesn't, and generate an error.  A program that accepts misformatted input is incorrect.

Comment: @JamesKanze "The program wouldn't be correct without them" I can't seem to make sense of that. It seems like you're trying to make the argument that the program external to this code is responsible for checking that there is only a `book` on each line before using the the extraction operator. That's one way to do it I guess, It doesn't conform to the behavior of the standard extraction operators though. It might be worth your time to look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_iterator/

Comment: @JonathanMee A program that reads external data, and does not validate its format, is incorrect.  How that format is defined may vary; C++ certainly ignores line breaks, for example.  But the format he presented seemed to me to be line oriented.  Otherwise, he'll need some other (possibly more complex) solution.  The question is: what defines the end of a record?  If it is only the trailing `]`, and line endings are just white space, then he probably needs to read one character at a time, building up a string with the record, rather than using `getline`.

Comment: @JamesKanze What defined the end of a number? The last character in that number. That's how the standard extraction operators work. That allows us to work effectively chaining extraction streams, rather than reading, "one character at a time" (Thank goodness.) What defines the end of a `book`? I'd suggest the last character in the `book`. (`]`) Again that will allow us to read more than one character at a time.

Comment: @JonathanMee What defines a record?  Each type defines its own constraints.  In this case, you can't use simple `']``, because that may occur in the title.  (There is, presumably, a reason why the title is in quotes.)  You need something that can't occur anywhere else in the value.  Line based records are ubiquitous in data processing; it seems reasonable to use them here.

Comment: @JonathanMee Whether one prefers putting everything in the `>>` operator, or having a separate parser which reads the lines and parses them is a separate question.  I generally prefer the separate parser; it seems to make it simpler to ignore empty lines and to handle comments (both of which I consider important for text formats).  My point is just that _if_ you're going to use the `>>` operator, it must validate the input according to the specified format, regardless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71782/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-james-kanze).

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer. And also the idea from Jonathan: istream_iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Your input string is well delimited so I'd recommend using an extraction operator over a `regex`, for speed and for ease of use.

You'd first need to create a `struct` for your books:

```
struct book{
    string author;
    string title;
    int pages;
    string code;
    string status;
};
```

Then you'd need to write the actual extraction operator:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& lhs, book& rhs){
    lhs >> ws;
    getline(lhs, rhs.author, ',');
    lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"');
    getline(lhs, rhs.title, '"');
    lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '(');
    lhs >> rhs.pages;
    lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '[');
    lhs >> rhs.code >> ws;
    getline(lhs, rhs.status, ']');
    return lhs;
}
```

This gives you a tremendous amount of power. For example you can extract all the books from an `istream` into a `vector` like this:

```
istringstream foo("P.G. Wodehouse, \"Heavy Weather\" (336 pp.) [PH.409 AVAILABLE FOR LENDING]\nJohn Bunyan, \"The Pilgrim's Progress\" (336 pp.) [E.1173 CHECKED OUT]");
vector<book> bar{ istream_iterator<book>(foo), istream_iterator<book>() };
```

Comment: Defining a `<<` operator is definitely an idea worth considering, but even in such cases, I'd have the `<<` use `std::getline`, and then use a regular expression to extract the data.  Your example code, for example, ignores line boundaries, making it almost impossible to resynchronize in case of a syntax error.  (It also fails if there is extra white space following the `']'`  Say an `'\r'` because the file was written on Windows, but is being read on Unix.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ummm... I'm very uncertain what you're talking about. "ignores boundaries?" It uses the same boundaries as I'd assume one would use in a regex. Though maybe you're talking about something else? It also clearly eats whitespace with the final `lhs >> ws;` call, example here: http://ideone.com/e.js/RsTGfo

Comment: I'd missed the `lhs >> ws`.  However, the issue remains; in Python, you'd read the input line by line, and resynchronize on the next line in case of an error.  The regular expression solution would do the same, using `std::getline`, and then parsing the line; after any error, the next input would read the next line.  In your code, if a line gets truncated for any reason, you're not going to see an error, and you'll get some very strange values from then on out.

Comment: @JamesKanze If that's a concern you could obviously handle it the way that you *must* handle an input file for regexes (operating on a line at a time.) The extraction operator simply gives you the ability to use `istream_iterators` and just read the entire file into a `vector` in one line.

Comment: `istream_iterator` is rarely useful in practice because it of the problems involving error handling.  But there's nothing wrong with using `std::getline` and `std::regex` within the `operator>>`; for line oriented records, it even works quite well.

Comment: @JamesKanze That is true, but it's less efficient, and since the question is one of efficiency, I prefer the stream operators. But at the end of the day my preference is all that is. A `regex` can certainly be used to solve this problem if that's your preference.

Comment: First, the choice between stream operators or not is orthogonal to the choice to use regular expressions or not.  Regular expressions are simply the easiest (most efficient in programmer time and effort) to ensure the required syntax, something that you must do regardless.  The alternative is basically writing a (simple) parser yourself for the desired syntax.  (If you're reading from a file, it's highly unlikely that the regular expression is going to make a significant difference in performance; the bottle neck will still be getting the data from disk into your process.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71693/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-james-kanze).

Answer (score 2):

Use flex (it generates C or C++ code, to be used as a part or as the full program)

```
%%
^[^,]+/,          {printf("Autor: %s\n",yytext  );}
\"[^"]+\"         {printf("Title: %s\n",yytext  );}
\([^ ]+/[ ]pp\.   {printf("Pages: %s\n",yytext+1);}
..................
.|\n              {}
%%
```

(untested)

Comment: Why do simple when you can do complicated?  (Flex is a very useful tool, but in this case, it's clearly overkill.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, you are right of course. Well, we never know the evolution of the problem... Anyway a 6 lines flex answer fitted better in my short coffee brake window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string extract (string a)
{
    string str = "AUTHOR = "; //the result string
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != ',')
        str += a[i++];
    while (a[i++] != '\"');

    str += "\nTITLE = ";
    while (a[i] != '\"')
        str += a[i++];
    while (a[i++] != '(');

    str += "\nPAGES = ";
    while (a[i] != ' ')
        str += a[i++];
    while (a[i++] != '[');

    str += "\nCODE = ";
    while (a[i] != ' ')
        str += a[i++];
    while (a[i++] == ' ');

    str += "\nSTATUS = ";
    while (a[i] != ']')
        str += a[i++];
    return str;
}

int main ()
{
    string a;
    getline (cin, a);
    cout << extract (a) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Wait, you're taking in a string he wants to extract and you're giving him back a different format to extract?

Comment: Oh yeah I think you're right @JonathanMee but he can easily change the format. I'll update my answer.